# Ошибка при создании нового проекта в Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Я начинающий бестолковый программист в среде Android Studio 2.3.3. При попытке создания нового проекта, возникла ошибка `"A problem occurred configuring project ':mobile'"`

Подскажите пожалуйста, что это и что с этим делать?

Comment: Ну, как минимум, привести полный лог ошибки

Comment: Gradle sync failed: A problem occurred configuring project ':mobile'.
   Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Это он?

Comment: Откройте лог гредла, там более подробно должно быть

Comment: Захожу в Help/Show log, оно открывает папку log, содержащую ряд папок и файлов. Что оттуда нужно? Извините, что морочу голову.

Comment: Справа снизу(в самом низу) закладка "Gradle console"

Comment: Нашёл, нажал, пустое окошко.

Comment: Пустое окно выдает

Comment: Так, давайте с другой стороны подойдем. Добейтесь возникновения этой ошибки, сделайте скриншот и добавьте его в вопрос. Пока слишком мало данных для анализа

Comment: Чего-то не крепится принт-скрин к комментарию...

А может иметь значение, что в окне Android monitor пишет Please configure Android SDK?

Comment: Конечно же нет!  Это был сарказм :) У вас в `build.gradle` указаны версия Android SDK, которая не установлена. Покажите свой `build.gradle` (ну либо сами посмотрите и установите необходимую версию)

Comment: Извините, дурака, а где его посмотреть или найти, чтобы вам выслать?

Comment: В левой панели, сверху, выберите вид отображения "Android", там должны отобразиться `gradle` скрипты вашего проекта. PS А у вас в принципе Android SDK установлен?

Comment: Нашел build.gradle вроде. Это оно?

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

SDK вроде установил вместе со студио